# How do I make this “Convert” button translate text from an input to binary?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a basic website which can convert text to binary using JavaScript, but I don’t really know how to make the <kbd>Convert!</kbd> button work. Does anyone have a simple fix that I can use? (Don’t mind the CSS missing some code, I’m not finished.)

```js
function convert() {
  const input_el = document.querySelector(".input-text");
  const output_el = document.querySelector(".output-binary");

  input_el.addEventListener("input", (event) => {
    let input_text = event.target.value;
    let output_arr = [];
    
    for (var i = 0; i < input_text.length; i++) {
      output_arr.push(input_text.charCodeAt(i).toString(2));
    }
    
    output_el.innerHTML = output_arr.join(" ");
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  padding: 30px;
  background: #09A954;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.navbar {
  padding: 12px;
  background: #363636;
  color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 80px;
  background: #B3B3B3;
}

.input_box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 40px;
  background: #D35400;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px #000000;
  height: 100px;
  width: ;
}

input {
  background: #D35400;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
  font-size: 15px;
}

button {
  width: 100px;
}

.output_box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 40px;
  background: #2980B9;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px #000000;
  height: 100px;
  width: ;
}

p2 {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: calibri;
}

p4 {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: arial;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Text to binary converter</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Text to binary converter</h1>
  </header>

  <div class="navbar">
    <p1>link</p1>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="input_box">
      <p2>This is what a human sees:</p2><br>
      <p3>Please enter text below</p3><br>
      <input type="text" name="" class="input-text">
    </div><br><br>

    <button onclick="convert()">Convert!</button><br><br>

    <div class="output_box">
      <p2>This is what a machine sees:</p2><br>
      <p4 class="output-binary"></p4>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Link to JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/SaltySandwich/65te8omy/

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It looks like you haven't included the code for your `convert()` function, could you include it, please?

Comment: @CoodleNoodle The `convert` function is right there.

Comment: Your `convert` does nothing except bind another event listener. You don’t need to bind another one here; instead just do the conversion in `convert`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed your exisiting project.
I took an easier aproach at JavaScript. You can write everything you need in 6 lines on JavaScript code :)
For your output, you should use the `<output>` instead of `<input>`.
Take a look at this:

```js
function convert() {
  var output = document.getElementById("output_text");
  var input = document.getElementById("input_text").value;
  output.value = "";
  for (i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    output.value += input[i].charCodeAt(0).toString(2) + " ";
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  padding: 30px;
  background: #09A954;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.navbar {
  padding: 12px;
  background: #363636;
  color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 80px;
  background: #B3B3B3;
}

.input_box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 40px;
  background: #D35400;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px #000000;
  height: 100px;
  width: ;
}

input {
  background: #D35400;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
  font-size: 15px;
}

input:focus {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
  font-size: 15px;
  outline: none;
}

button {
  width: 100px;
}

.output_box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 40px;
  background: #2980B9;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px #000000;
  height: 100px;
  width: ;
}

p2 {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: calibri;
}

p4 {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: arial;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Text to binary converter</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Text to binary converter</h1>
  </header>

  <div class="navbar">
    <p1>link</p1>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="input_box">
      <p2>This is what a human sees:</p2><br>
      <p3>Please enter text below</p3><br>
      <!--INPUT FIELD-->
      <input id="input_text" value="Human sees this" />
    </div><br><br>

    <button onclick="convert()">Convert!</button><br><br>

    <div class="output_box">
      <p2>This is what a machine sees:</p2><br>
      <!--INPUT FIELD-->
      <output id="output_text">
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="main.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Ohh.. I also edited your CSS a little bit so the input doesn't have the annoying border around it... You can delete my changes by deleting this:

```css
  input:focus {
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
    font-size: 15px;
    outline: none;
  }
```

If you need anything cleared out be sure to comment under this post :)

Comment: You're very welcome! If you ever need anything else, be sure to ask :)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this:

```js
function convert() {
    var  output=document.getElementById("ti2");  
    var input=document.getElementById("ti1").value;
      output.value = "";
      for (i=0; i < input.length; i++) {
           output.value +=input[i].charCodeAt(0).toString(2) + " ";
      }
  }
```

```css
input {font-size:12px; width:200px;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="ti1" value ="Human sees this"/>
        <input id="ti2" value ="Machine sees this"/>
        <button onclick="convert();">Convert!</button>
        <script src="main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

It should give you the basic idea...

Comment: Sorry but im very new to coding in HTML and Javascript, so the code you posted dosn't really help me that much. But do you happen to know why my script isn't working?

Comment: I'll look into it now and let you know asap :)